# Cannot get Drawable id referenced from another resource file

Tags: android, android-resources, android-drawable

Here is what I have:

In res/drawable-hdpi I have this image:

```
ar_contact
```

In res/values I have this file:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="articles_images_thumbnail_array">
        <item>@drawable/ar_contact</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I want to get the id of my image from the string-array (I will have more than one image)

Now when I tried that in code, I got only the path to the image as a String:

```
res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ar_contact.png
```

This is my tried code:

```
id = resources.getStringArray(R.array.articles_images_thumbnail_array)[articleIndex];
```

The above Java code returns the path as String, But I want the id of the ar_contact image so I can use it as such:

```
imageThumbnail.setImageResource(id);
```

I have tried to use integer-array but I got only a 0 value for all my images.

Comment: out of all the questions, why can't you just use R.drawable.ar_contact?

Comment: @blackbelt You may find a better alternative for me :) Here is why: The app will list articles with one ICON and one Image. I save articles which are static and are very limited in number, 5 or 7 articles in XML Resource files. I have arrays for articles, icons and images. ICON and Image at indices of 0 associated with article at index of 0. I want to ship images with my app not to get them downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should instead use a `TypedArray` as said in [Resources API guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray) :

```
<resources>
    <array name="articles_images_thumbnail_array">
        <item>@drawable/ar_contact</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

Then retrieve the array like this :

```
TypedArray array = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.articles_images_thumnail_array);
Drawable myDrawable = array.getDrawable(0); // Returns @drawable/ar_contact
```